# WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms to minify entire aspx file

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How can I used WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms to minify the entire aspx file ?
Also is there a way this can be done at the master page level and minify everything ?